# String-encoding SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a very strange issue. I have a SQL statement that works locally, but the same statement does not work on a remote ubuntu machine (same mysql version). I think it has to do with how the SQL string is being encoded by the driver. Here is the statement I have:

```
group_ids = ('43ede7a1e1f048872c025867602dc54d', '43ede7a1e1f048872c025867602dc54d', '7a8ec12901c43606aee041f1e6d5b2d4', '0f57f4ad
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute( '''
    SELECT
        DISTINCT c.group_id
    FROM
        main_cue c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        main_passongroup p
            ON
        (c.group_id=p.group_id AND p.user_id=%s)
    WHERE 
        c.group_id in %s
    ORDER BY
        p.timestamp ASC, c.id DESC''',  (user.pk, group_ids))

results = cursor.fetchall()
print '>>> 1', results
```

On my local machine, it seems to be properly SQL-encoding the statement, but on the remote server, it is only working if I hard code the **exact** sql statement.

Is there a better way to encode the SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with an outdated version of `MySQLdb`, which was not properly encoding the string.

I was able to solve this by uninstalling MySQLdb and then reinstalling the newer version, (`MySQL-python==1.2.5`).